# Char and int into the same array

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I want to store integers and characters in the same array. Like:
EA1001 or EB1254
they are supposed to be identity codes.
It doesn't necessarily have to be an array, just something I can use to store these kind of strings together or else it becomes difficult for me to use them redundantly.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: That is all `char`, not `int`. If you somehow need to do some numeric stuff on the number (which I doubt you'd do), then you need to parse the id and store in a `struct`/`class`.

Comment: Why you don't store it as `char`?

Comment: "EA1001" looks like a string, and so does "EB1254", simply have a `std::set<std::string>` which holds all these "codes"

Answer (score 2):

Can't you store them as strings? E.g.

```
std::vector<std::string> my_codes;
my_codes.push_back("EA1001");
my_codes.push_back("EB1254");
```

Answer (score 0):

answer is array of unions. But this can be dangerous.

```
union
{
    char char_var;
    int int_var;
}same_array;
```

and do the declaration:

```
same_array my_array[1000];
```

because int is 16 or 32 bits while char is 8 bits. thats the only way representing a 32 bit area for both int and char

Comment: This doesn't really follow the logic of the question, where it's just a string, followed by an int.

Answer (score 0):

The most reasonable solution would be using `std::string`. From your question it seems that you neeed just to hold strings that can contain numbers:

```
std::string a = "EA112312";
```

If you want a set of those, use `std::vector` with it's element being strings:

```
std::vector< std::string >vec;
vec.push_back(a);//adding an element to the vector, where a is a string.
```

Well, actually, you can even do something ilke this:

```
int a = 'm';
std::cout << (char)a;
```

so technicaly it's possible to store both numbers and characters in an array of `int`s, but that would be.. uh... weird.